# VBA Script to add (copy) the inputs of a selected cell into cells in another column

Tags: vba, excel, google-sheets

I'm completely new to VBA. Would love any tips, hints, and help to figure this out. Thank you!

--

I have a Google spreadsheet, in which I have drawn a button and named it "Add This". When this button is clicked (after assigning the script), I hope to execute the following operation -

**Part 1.**
Cell A1 is the selected input cell in which I would enter a value, for example "Apple". When I click the "Add This" button, the script should copy the value presently in Cell A1 and paste it into a cell in column B.

Now if the value in Cell A1 were changed, the value in the pasted cell in Column B should not change.

**Part 2.**
When I input a new value into Cell A1, for example "Orange", and click "Add This", the script should copy this new value in A1 and paste it in the next blank cell in Column B.

Likewise if i do this again with a 3rd, 4th, or 5th... value, the script should copy the value in A1 (if i click the button) and add it into the next blank cell in Column B. The end result would look something like - 
[example image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5g8pluadtoxsqo0/Screen%20Shot%202015-02-26%20at%2010.49.30.png?dl=0)

**Part 3.**
Column C would be a date stamp of when the script was run (i.e., "Add This" button was clicked.

This is all I could come up with so far -

```
function copydata() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 

var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

  sheet1.getRange('Sheet1!C2:C5').copyTo(sheet1.getRange('Sheet1!F2:F5'));

}
```

Comment: We are not here to write code for you. Show us what you have tried and what specific problems or difficulties you're having.

Comment: This site is used to help you problem solve your code or issue, not write your code for you.  You need to first make an attempt and post your code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is simple code to get you started:

```
Sub ButtonCode()
    Dim N As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Cells(1, 1).Copy Cells(N, 2)
    Cells(N, 3).Value = Date
End Sub
```

Cell **B1** will not be affected and is available for a header.